# Как округлить строчку или преобразовать его в цифру Python

Tags: python

мне нужно вывести частоту CPU(max) в консоль, с помощью кода:

```
cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
cpu = (f"Max Frequency: {cpufreq.max:.2f}Mhz")
print(cpu)
```

Он выводит 5100.00mhz
Я хочу, что бы он вывел 5.1Mhz.
Как преобразовать эту строку в int?

Comment: 5.1 - это не int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cpu = f"Max Frequency: {cpufreq.max/1000:.1f}GHz" # Max Frequency: 5.1GHz
```

Это будут уже ГГц, а не МГц.

`.1f` означает округлять до 1 знака после запятой.